# Rectangle Physics Body Causing angular changes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have a rectangular sprite that forms the border of my screen. I also have smaller moving rectangular sprites moving in straight, horizontal lines.

Even though they are moving, (because of the rectangular physics bodies), the sprites should not rotate. For some reason, the enemy ship sprites begin rotating after hitting the border sprite a few times.

My code below (the attack ship is the one getting rotated incorrectly):

```
    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    setUpHeaderUI()
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector.zero
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    createBG()
    addShip()

    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
    self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = shipCategory | enemyShipCategory
    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = wallCategory
    self.physicsBody?.friction = 0

func addAttackShip(){
    //30,40,40
    let enemy = attackShip.init()
    enemy.setScale(0.08)
    enemy.zRotation = CGFloat(0)
    enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(rectangleOf: enemy.size)
    enemy.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    enemy.name = "enemy"
    enemy.zPosition = 2
    enemy.physicsBody?.mass = CGFloat.init(10)
    enemy.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = enemyShipCategory
    enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = enemyShipCategory | wallCategory
    enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = greenBulletCategory | shipCategory
    enemy.position = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 155.504 - enemy.size.height / 2)
    enemy.zRotation = CGFloat(2.4870942)

   let healthindicator = SKSpriteNode.init(color: UIColor.green, size: CGSize.init(width: 150, height: 30))
    healthindicator.name = "healthdisplay"
    healthindicator.zPosition = 3
    healthindicator.zRotation = -1 * CGFloat(2.4870942)
    enemy.addChild(healthindicator)
    addChild(enemy)
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what exactly is the problem? The ship is supposed to rotate but doesn't? If so, when is it supposed to rotate, and what causes it to rotate?

Comment: @Fluidity The enemyShip sprite should not rotate at all but for some reason it rotates after a few collisions with the border.

Comment: hey there, did my answer work for you? If not, I can try to update it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
let enemy = SKSpriteNode()
enemy.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
// Put the correct value in the skrange:
enemy.constraints =  [SKConstraint.zRotation(SKRange(constantValue: 0)]
```